# Springs Qualifier Error creating bean with name 'circle': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCenter' parameter

Tags: spring

I'm learning Springs and while learning @Autowiring, came across @Qualifier. I've declared a qualifier but still, there is an exception thrown.

Below is my Code
Spring.xml:

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.SpringDemo" />

<bean id="circle" class="com.SpringDemo.Circle" > </bean>

   <bean id="pointA" class="com.SpringDemo.Point"> 
         <qualifier value="circleRelated"> </qualifier>
         <property name="x"  value="${pointA.pointX}"></property>
         <property name="y"  value="${pointA.pointY}"></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="pointB" class="com.SpringDemo.Point">                            
         <property name="x"  value="${pointB.pointX}"></property>
         <property name="y"  value="${pointB.pointY}"></property>
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="pointC" class="com.SpringDemo.Point"> 
         <property name="x"  value="${pointC.pointX}"></property>
         <property name="y"  value="${pointC.pointY}"></property>
   </bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
<property name="locations" value="resource/pointsconfig.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please post the Circle class.

Comment: Have a look at this it might help..https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers